# World of Trucks not synchronizing

Tags: euro-truck-simulator-2

I got ETS2 the other day and saw they had an event going. Truck to/from 10 different countries from/to Germany, routes over 300km.

Naturally, I wanted to help. But it's not registering my progress.

I registered a World of Trucks account and connected it. Still, it does not register my rides. What could I have screwed up?

[image: Profile with no jobs]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First things first: it was synchronizing when it needed to. It simply didn't need to, yet. It only synchronizes World of Trucks delivery contracts ("External contracts").

It's not mentioned anywhere in the challenge, but only WoT deliveries are counted. It is only vaguely implied.

> Complete 10 total deliveries of any cargo between Germany and 10 other different countries in Euro Truck Simulator 2. Each delivery must be at least 300km.
>
> This is also a community event. The entire community is required to deliver 15.000.000 tons of cargo in total to Germany from any other country or vice versa. There is no distance limit for the community deliveries.

Note how they speak about the community? That's the WoT community. It's a WoT event which only counts WoT contracts. Quick jobs and other jobs **do not** count.

Get your own truck, start trucking external jobs, and all of a sudden you're making progress!

[image: Profile with jobs]
[image: Progress]